# Laplace transform of $L({1-e^{-t}\over t})$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

I have to find the Laplace transform of $$\mathcal{L}\left[\dfrac{1-e^{-t}}t\right],$$ then this is equivalent to $$\mathcal{L}\left[\dfrac{1}t\right]-\mathcal{L}\left[\dfrac{e^{-t}}t\right]$$

But $\mathcal{L}\left[\dfrac{1}t\right]$ doesn't exist right?  Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You might want to review the [Laplace Transform's properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) - the $7^{th}$ in particuar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[f(t)\right]=F(s)=\int_0^\infty f(t)\ e^{-st}\ dt
$$
and property of the unilateral Laplace transform
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{f(t)}{t}\right]=\int_s^\infty F(\omega)\ d\omega,
$$
where $F(\omega)$ is Laplace transform of $f(t)$. We choose $f(t)=(1-e^{-t})$ and it is easy to show that
$$
F(s)=\mathcal{L}\left[1-e^{-t}\right]=\frac1s-\frac1{s+1}
$$
then
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\right]&=\int_s^\infty F(\omega)\ d\omega\\
&=\int_s^\infty \left(\frac1\omega-\frac1{\omega+1}\right)\ d\omega\\
&=\left.\left[\ln \omega-\ln(\omega+1)\right]\right|_s^\infty\\
&=\left.\ln\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega+1}\right)\right|_s^\infty\\
&=-\ln\left(\frac{s}{s+1}\right)\\
&=\large\color{blue}{\ln\left(\frac{s+1}{s}\right)},
\end{align}
where $\displaystyle\lim_{\omega\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega+1}\right)=0$.

Comment: This answer makes no sense - it should be a function of $s$.

Comment: @RonGordon Is this OK now?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey :In $\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{f(t)}{t}\right]=\int_s^\infty F(\omega)\ d\omega,$ is $F(\omega)$ the laplace transform of $f(t)$.In my note it is given that $\int _s^\infty F(s')ds'$.Why can't it be written like $\int _s^\infty F(s)ds$ if $F(s')$ (your $F(\omega)$ ) is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$.Why use another variable $s'$.ALso can you please explain how $\displaystyle\lim_{\omega\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega+1}\right)=0$

Comment: @clarkson My math and stat prof always says, never use this term $\displaystyle\int_s^\infty F(s)\ ds$, you must use a dummy variable here. Hence, as a good student, I use $\displaystyle\int_s^\infty F(\omega)\ d\omega$ instead. About the limit, since the term $\dfrac{\omega}{\omega+1}$ yields an indeterminate form $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$, then apply L'Hospital rule here.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey : Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Tunk-Fey How can I prove $\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{f(t)}{t}\right]=\int_s^\infty F(\omega)\ d\omega,$

Comment: @sam_rox: Click this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems). This is deduced using the nature of frequency differentiation and conditional convergence.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 - \expo{-t} \over t}\,\expo{-st}\,\dd t}
=-\int_{0}^{\infty}
\ln\pars{t}\bracks{-s\expo{-st} + \pars{s + 1}\expo{-\pars{s + 1}t}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t \over s}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t \over s + 1}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{s + 1 \over s}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{1 + {1 \over s}}}
\end{align}

Comment: A bit explanation would suffice. But still +1 from me, as always.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Line 1 is 'Integration by Parts'. In Line 2 we scale the variables in both integrals: First is $st \mapsto t$ and second $\left(s + 1\right)t \mapsto t$. That cancels 'the $t$' in the logarithm. The remaining integral is one. It's a kind of [Frullani's Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html). Thanks.